# Draw part of an image onto a widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to draw a sprite onto a CustomPaint widget. The sprite comes from an image containing multiple sprites in a grid, so I need to be able to specify the source rectangle (and preferably a destination rectangle that matches the size of the widget).

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this using canvas.drawAtlas:

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class SquarePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image theImage;
  SquarePainter({this.theImage});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    canvas.drawAtlas(
        theImage,
        [
          /* Identity transform */
          RSTransform.fromComponents(
              rotation: 0.0,
              scale: 1.0,
              anchorX: 0.0,
              anchorY: 0.0,
              translateX: 0.0,
              translateY: 0.0)
        ],
        [
            /* A 5x5 source rectangle within the image at position (10, 10) */
            Rect.fromLTWH(10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0)
        ],
        [/* No need for colors */],
        BlendMode.src,
        null /* No need for cullRect */,
        Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(SquarePainter oldDelegate) => false;
  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(SquarePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: What is the `drawAtlas` all about?

Comment: @Suragch Draws a part of image! https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawAtlas.html

Comment: Is there any way we can get a Circle instead of a square?